# get label within the addEdge event

Tags: vis.js

How can I get information about the node within the addEdge event. I managed to get the start and the end node ids but is there a possibility to get more information about the node itself? edgeData only contains 2 objects "from" and "to"

```
    var optionsFA = {                                                                                                                                                                         
      manipulation: {                                                                                                                                                                         
        enabled: true,                                                                                                                                                                        
        addEdge: function (edgeData,callback) {                                                                                                                                               
            console.log('from: ' + edgeData.from + ' / to: ' + edgeData.to);
callback(edgeData);}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [dataset](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html#Methods) then there is an object search function by id:

```
addEdge: function(edge, callback) {
  var from = data.nodes.get(edge.from)
  var to = data.nodes.get(edge.to)
  console.log('from:', from)
  console.log('to:', to)
  callback(edge)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ev0h9tdz/

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for, thanks a bunch! But I would like to understand why "data"? it is not declared in the fiddle. is this a dedicated object delivered by the addEdge call?

Comment: data is declared in the string number two: `var data = getScaleFreeNetwork(10)`

Comment: sure thing, oversaw that. I create the Dataset objects, then use them when initiating the Network object (as well as the options object). This is great! Thanks, this is much clearer!